# can i use pen drive for booting os into beagle board xm instead of sd card

Tags: operating-system, embedded-linux, opensuse

https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:BeagleBoard-xM

please any body help me
please any body help me

please any body help me

Answer (score 0):

First you must read Documentation of TI DM3730, because botting from USB require set high or low state on certian pins. Next you must properly formated USB storage. This mean shared on concret partition FAT32 for u-boot, and example ext3 for rootfs. All this info you should be give for manufactures of your board.